# Socket- não recebe a mensagem por completo

Tags: java

Tenho esses códigos.:
Estou fazendo testes ainda...

Sistema cliente:

```
private void btComunicarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        List<PessoaMOD> pessoas = new ArrayList<PessoaMOD>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 400; i++) {
            pessoas.add(new PessoaMOD(i,
                    "Pessoa " + i,
                    "111.111.111.11",
                    "11.111.111-1",
                    "Rua Violetas " + i,
                    "Numero " + i,
                    "Complemento " + i,
                    "Bairro " + i,
                    "Cidade " + i,
                    "Estado" + i,
                    "Telefone 1" + i,
                    "Telefone 2" + i,
                    "Email" + i,
                    'f'));
        }

        try {
            Socket cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 12345);
            enviarMensagem(serializarPessoa(pessoas), cliente);
            cliente.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
        }
    }                                           

    public byte[] serializarPessoa(List<PessoaMOD> pessoas) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
        dos.writeInt(pessoas.size()); // tamanho da lista
        int cont = 0;
        for (PessoaMOD p : pessoas) {
            dos.writeInt(p.getId()); // id da pessoa
            dos.writeUTF(p.getNome());
            dos.writeUTF(p.getCpf());
            dos.writeUTF(p.getRg());
            dos.writeUTF(p.getEndereco());
            dos.writeUTF(p.getNumero());
            dos.writeUTF(p.getComplemento());
            dos.writeUTF(p.getBairro());
            dos.writeUTF(p.getCidade());
            dos.writeUTF(p.getEstado());
            dos.writeUTF(p.getTelefone1());
            dos.writeUTF(p.getTelefone2());
            dos.writeUTF(p.getEmail());
            dos.writeChar(p.getPerfil());//Nome da pessoa
        }
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    public void enviarMensagem(byte[] mensagem, Socket socket) throws IOException {
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("Lenght: " + mensagem.length);
        out.writeInt(mensagem.length); //O tamanho da mensagem
        out.write(mensagem); //Os dados
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
```

Sistema servidor:

```
private void btIniciarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(12345);
                    System.out.println("Servidor ouvindo a porta 12345");
                    while (true) {
                        Socket cliente = servidor.accept();
                        DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());

                        int tamanhoMsg = entrada.readInt();
                        System.out.println("Tam. Msg.: " + tamanhoMsg);

                        byte[] bytes = new byte[tamanhoMsg];
                        entrada.read(bytes, 0 , bytes.length);
                        System.out.println("Bytes size: " + bytes.length);

                        DataInputStream entrada2 = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));

                        int tamanhoLista = entrada2.readInt();

                        int id;
                        String nome;
                        String cpf;
                        String rg;
                        String endereco;
                        String numero;
                        String complemento;
                        String bairro;
                        String cidade;
                        String estado;
                        String telefone1;
                        String telefone2;
                        String email;
                        char perfil;

                        for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoLista; i++) {
                            id = entrada2.readInt();
                            nome = entrada2.readUTF();
                            cpf = entrada2.readUTF();
                            rg = entrada2.readUTF();
                            endereco = entrada2.readUTF();
                            numero = entrada2.readUTF();
                            complemento = entrada2.readUTF();
                            bairro = entrada2.readUTF();
                            cidade = entrada2.readUTF();
                            estado = entrada2.readUTF();
                            telefone1 = entrada2.readUTF();
                            telefone2 = entrada2.readUTF();
                            email = entrada2.readUTF();
                            perfil = entrada2.readChar();

                            System.out.println("Id: " + id);
                            System.out.println("Nome: " + nome);
                            System.out.println("Cpf: " + cpf);
                            System.out.println("Rg: " + rg);
                            System.out.println("Endereço: " + endereco);
                            System.out.println("Número: " + numero);
                            System.out.println("Complemento: " + complemento);
                            System.out.println("Bairro: " + bairro);
                            System.out.println("Cidade: " + cidade);
                            System.out.println("Estado: " + estado);
                            System.out.println("Telefone 1: " + telefone1);
                            System.out.println("Telefone 2: " + telefone2);
                            System.out.println("Email: " + email);
                            System.out.println("Perfil: " + perfil);
                            System.out.println("");
                        }
                        entrada.close();
                        entrada2.close();
                        cliente.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Acontece que a mensagem não vem completa, tem vez que executo e a lista vem ate a pessoa 37, as vezes ate a pessoa 392, cada hora vem um  tanto de pesssoa da lista...

A variavel de **tamanho da mensagem** e a de **tamanho da lista** estão vindo certo...

Answer (score 3):

Você está chamando entrada.read() apenas uma vez. Nesse caso ele não vai esperar até ter bytes suficientes para encher o buffer; vai retornar logo que tiver alguma coisa recebida, mesmo que seja 1 byte. Se ele devolver 0 bytes é porque a conexão foi interrompida. Enquanto a conexão existir o read() espera. Tipicamente ele vai entregar, a cada retorno, o que cabe em um pacote TCP, cujo tamanho varia de 60 a uns 1400 bytes.

A solução é fazer um loop e chamar read() várias vezes até ter lido a quantidade esperada de bytes (e tratar o caso de receber 0 bytes)

Answer (score 3):

Como o @epx já mencionou, os dados são transmitidos pela rede em blocos, então é preciso um loop para recompor os blocos de dados até a quantidade total de bytes esperada ser recebida.

Uma vantagem de usar serialização com `ObjectOutputStream` e `ObjectInputStream` é que essas classes já tem o controle necessário para enviar e ler a quantidade correta de bytes.

Para resolver o problema no seu caso, sem o uso de outras classes, você pode usar o método `readFully()` que já contém o loop. Exemplo:

```
entrada.readFully(bytes);
```

Para você ter uma ideia do que ele faz, a implementação do método que realmente é executado é assim:

```
public final void readFully(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
    if (len < 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    int n = 0;
    while (n < len) {
        int count = in.read(b, off + n, len - n);
        if (count < 0)
            throw new EOFException();
        n += count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Com certeza esta é a resposta ideal